# Pixel errors rotating image with emgucv in c#

Tags: c#, rotation, emgucv

I am trying to rotate an image using emgucv with GetRotationMatrix2D and WarpAffine. I have tried different methods to rotate the image and while this one seems the best so far, it seems to sometime produce wrong pixels.

I used the following methods to read an image into a Mat object and rotate it.

```
public static void LoadImage(string filepath, Mat target, ImreadModes mode = ImreadModes.Grayscale | ImreadModes.AnyDepth)
{
    using (var mat = CvInvoke.Imread(filepath, mode))
    {
        if (mat == null || mat.Size == System.Drawing.Size.Empty)
            throw new System.IO.IOException($"Image file '{filepath}'           is not readable.");
        mat.CopyTo(target);
    }
}

void rotateMat(ref Mat src, double angle)
{
    Mat r = new Mat();
    PointF pc = new PointF((float)(src.Cols / 2.0), (float)(src.Rows / 2.0));
    CvInvoke.GetRotationMatrix2D(pc, angle, 1.0, r);
    CvInvoke.WarpAffine(src, src, r, src.Size);
}

.....
Mat image = new Mat();
LoadImage("./test.tif", image);
rotateMat(ref image, frameRotation);
.....
```

This code works without errors, but in some cases parts of the image overlap with each other, as if the rotation was applied to image segments separately. I am working with 16-bit Tiff files.

Here is the result I obtain after rotating the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiHvk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Rotation Matrix have you tried using a RotatedRect instead? I use this technique when I want to copy a ROI defined by a RotatedRect from a source image to a destination image. It should work for any image. Here is an example Windows Console program that demonstrates this concept:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mat source = new Mat("dog.jpg", ImreadModes.Unchanged);

    PointF center = new PointF(Convert.ToSingle(source.Width) / 2, Convert.ToSingle(source.Height) / 2);
    Mat destination = new Mat(new System.Drawing.Size(source.Width, source.Height), DepthType.Cv8U, 3);

    RotatedRect destRect = new RotatedRect(center, source.Size, 35);
    Rectangle bbox = destRect.MinAreaRect();

    RotateImage(ref source, ref destination, destRect);
    CvInvoke.Imshow("Source", source);
    CvInvoke.Imshow("Destination", destination);

    CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);
}

private static void RotateImage(ref Mat src, ref Mat destination, RotatedRect destRect)
{
    PointF[] destCorners = destRect.GetVertices();
    PointF[] srcCorners = new PointF[] {
            new PointF(0F, src.Height),
            new PointF(0F, 0F),
            new PointF(src.Width, 0F),
            new PointF(src.Width, src.Height)
    };

    using (Mat aft = CvInvoke.GetAffineTransform(srcCorners, destCorners))
    using (Mat warpResult = new Mat(src.Size, src.Depth, src.NumberOfChannels))
    {
        CvInvoke.WarpAffine(src, warpResult, aft, destination.Size);
        warpResult.CopyTo(destination);
    }
}
```

This quickie example will clip the resulting image. I will leave as an exercise for the reader to resize the destination to prevent clipping.

Doug

Comment: I didn't try this method because, as you mention, it clips the image. I could resize it, but since they are 16-bit images I want to limit the amount of operations on the original image to avoid losing information. I'll have another look though, thanks.

Comment: I do not think you will be losing very much information if resizing is necessary. If you are rotating the 180 degrees you do not need resizing. You could also reduce the size slightly to fit inside the resulting frame which would cause almost no loss of information.

If helpful please mark as an answer.